# Bash error code doesn't show in my shell prompt

Tags: bash

I'd like to incorporate the trick where I show the error code of the last command in my shell prompt. I've tried it - however it always only returns zero no matter what I ran.

Say I set the prompt to this:

```
export PS1="$? $ "
```

I get this output when I try typing correct and incorrect input:

```
0 $    
0 $ echo foo
foo
0 $ echo $?
0
0 $ echofoo
bash: echofoo: command not found
0 $ echo $?
127
0 $
```

So the error code is captured, but not displayed on the shell prompt. I would expect that when I ran `echofoo`, the next command line would show `127 $`, but it shows 0.

This happens too when I try running code which exits non-zero, e.g. this `bad.py` Python file:

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)

0 $ python bad.py
0 $ echo $?
1
0 $
```

Again, I can see that it exits non-zero, but the shell prompt doesn't reflect that.

How can I correctly display the error code of the previous command in the shell prompt? I would like to know the answer for both bash and tcsh, as I haven't managed to get this working in either shell.

Comment: The immediate problem is that using double quotes causes the _current_ value of `$?` to be frozen in the prompt you set. You want the variable to be evaluated when you display the prompt, not when you originally set the prompt.

Comment: As an aside, `PS1` is probably already `export`ed so there should be no reason to do it again.

Comment: What do you do to evaluate the variable on display, @tripleee?

Comment: Trivially, use single quotes instead of double when setting it.